# TYPO3 dependency injection with mpdf/mpdf

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm currently upgrading a TYPO3 extension from v9 to v10 which uses mpdf/mpdf.

In `Services.yaml` I've added

```
mPDF\:
  resource: '../../../../../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/'
```

But now I end up with this error message:

> Expected to find class "mPDF\MpdfException" in file
> "/var/www/xxxx/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/MpdfException.php" while importing
> services from resource "../../../../../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/*", but it was
> not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.

The problem is, that the class is `MpdfException` and not `mPDF\MpdfException`.

I tried to add

```
MpdfException\:
  resource: '../../../../../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/'
```

This didn't work.

Next I tried to add this to the global `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": { "mPDF\\": "vendor/mpdf/mpdf/" }
}
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: *mpdf* is available as a composer package and seems to have been installed via composer. So, normally, there's no need to specify something special because composer cares about autoloading... Maybe you are struggling over superfluous configuration....

Comment: Ehm... The vendor of *mpdf* is "Mpdf", not "mPDF"... The exception class is `\Mpdf\MpdfException` (https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/src/MpdfException.php)

Comment: What are you trying to do? How can one reproduce the problem? I've just required `mpdf/mpdf` (v8.0.13), had no entry for mpdf in my `Service.yaml` and my controller got a Mpdf\Mpdf-object via Constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your effort to help me, Julian! Much appreciated! It turned out that the extension had a requirement for an outdated version of mPDF. After using the latest version of mPDF it now works. Nevertheless I still need  `Services.yaml`.